# When does Flash compute/re-compute a blur effect on a DisplayObject?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, filter

Say I apply a Blur filter to a Sprite:

```
mySprite.filters = [new BlurFilter(...)];
```

When does Flash computes the filter?

- When I add a child to the Sprite?
- When I scale the Sprite?
- When I rotate the Sprite?
- When I apply alpha value on the Sprite?

Thanks for hepling

Eyal

Comment: not 100% sure, but I think it happens on every frame, if mySprite is Sprite or a Vector. If it is bitmap - than just when creating...

Answer (score 0):

The effect of a filter is recalculated, i.e. it is rendered, each frame if the display object is in the ["redraw region"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-421a65ed127736eaa26-8000.html) either because the display object itself is animated, or it's inside the redraw region of (an)other display object(s).

Comment: Thanks Creynders.


I read some code which adds 3 Bitmaps into a Sprite and change their location inside the Sprite on every ENTER_FRAME. 
But the code also applied a BlurFilter on every frame, and that looked very inefficient; So I now understand that it's probably really bad for performance, right? and would be better done with BitmapData, right again?

Comment: Almost certainly yes. (I suppose you're talking about blitting, right?) But the only way to know for sure is by testing it out. Animation optimization is tough, takes a lot of experimenting and constant profiling of memory use, frame rates etc. But it's deeply satisfying after you've spent 3 full days on getting that frame rate from a staggering 15 to a smooth 24+ :)